# Generating xdg menu lua files on Debian

Tags: debian, kali-linux, awesome, freedesktop, xdg

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a `menu.lua` for Awesome WM on Debian (actually Kali 2.0). In a nutshell it's a Lua file representing the structure of the Applications menu so it can be reproduced in Awesome's menu.

[This is the relevant section in the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-menu#With_xdg_menu), but I can't seem to find the equivalent on Debian. There doesn't seem to be and `Xdg-menu` counterpart.

**Update**

I tried `menu-xdg` from the Debian repos, as suggested in the comments, unfortunately this doesn't appear to be what I'm looking for:

```
root@kali:/etc/menu-methods# ./menu-xdg --help
install-menu [-vh] <menu-method>
  Read menu entries from stdin in "update-menus --stdout" format
  and generate menu files using the specified menu-method.
  Options to install-menu:
     -h --help    : this message
        --remove  : remove the menu instead of generating it.
     -v --verbose : be verbose
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since it wasn't really helpful after all. Have you tried extracting the file from the arch package?

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked! In case anyone else lands here, just download `xdg-menu` from the Arch Linux repos, extract it, you'll find the Perl script in the `usr/` folder. Then just follow the Arch Wiki.

Comment: Great! Do you think you could just quickly post that as an answer? That way the next person with this issue will know what to do and (if you remember to come back and accept your answer) you'll get some well-deserved rep!